# Avplayer is not playing with swift 3 (Xcode 8)

Tags: swift3, avplayer, ios10

please help me log is shown playing but no sound is heard

```
let url = URL(string: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/kargopolov/BlueCafe.mp3")
         let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url! as URL)
        let player=AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
        player.volume=1.0

        player.play()

        if (player.rate != 0 && player.error == nil) {
            print("playing")
        }
        else
        {
            print("error",player.error)
        }
```

Comment: your player is going out of scope, you need to assign it to an instance variable.

Comment: how to do that as i changed to let player=AVPlayer.init(playerItem: playerItem) still not playing

Answer (score 3):

You need a to assign the player to a variable that doesn't go out of scope, eg

```
class ViewControllerA: UIViewController {

    var avPlayer: AVPlayer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let videoURL = NSURL(string: "https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4")
        avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: videoURL! as URL)
        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)
        playerLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 3.0 / 4.0)
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        avPlayer.play()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare Player Variable before

```
 var playerT : AVPlayer!
```

Now you able to play song from url

```
let url = URL(string: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/kargopolov/BlueCafe.mp3")

                playerT = AVPlayer(url: url!)
                playerT.volume = 1.0
                playerT.play()

                if playerT.rate != 0 && playerT.error == nil{
                    print("Playing")
                }else{
                    print("Error Playing")
                }
```

Comment: be more descriptive in your answer